# c++ direct3d 2d rendering

Tags: c++, direct3d

i would like to know what you suggest me for the following problem:

All what i need is to display a surface in a win32 window. Say 256 * 256 xRGB and i need to get access to the memory to put pixels in it.
I was quite right with Direct3d9, but the API is old.
I know there are different ways to do the same in Dirct3D 10 and 11, But does it involve playing with 3d things? There is no way i think to do it in Direct3D10 or 11.
I used surface->Lock() in direct3D9, but it isn't available in newer ones.

So, said that if i have to use a lib (like SDL) which i cannot call directly to lock the surface and show in a win32 window. Is there some api to do 2d rendering in d3d or do i have to get into direct3d 10 or 11 and do it in 3d the hard way?

I have googled it and im kinda lost.
Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Are you using cuda to modify your pixels ?

Answer (score 3):

With DirectX, you can display an image as a quad (rectangle) with a texture, and you modify the texture (as an image) accordingly to your needs.

You can use any DX (9,10,11,12) to do so, but it's a lot of work to display just a 256x256 pixels image.

Here you have sample that achieve this: https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started,
in particular the sprites and texture https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Sprites-and-textures.

You can get some help here: https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DeviceResources.

I however find the sample not so direct to display a image that is computed.

If you're looking for the lowest latency possible (sub-millisecond), or being able to display in 10bits (you can only do so with DX), having a cuda enabled GPU you can display and modify an image all in the GPU with DX12: https://github.com/mprevot/CudaD3D12Update.

This is a case of cuda-DX12 interop. In that case you minimize the back and forth between the CPU and the GPU since the texture is computed and displayed in the GPU. The CPU is only here to orchestrize the events.

The quad is defined [as such:](https://github.com/mprevot/CudaD3D12Update/blob/e2284f4876059af492be9a8e68a5c587fd2ca7fb/simpleD3D12update.cpp#L299)

```
    TexVertex quadVertices[] =
    {
        { {-x,-y, 0.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f } },
        { {-x, y, 0.0f }, { 0.0f, 1.0f } },
        { {x, -y, 0.0f }, { 1.0f, 0.0f } },
        { {x,  y, 0.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f } },
    };
```

and then [uploaded](https://github.com/mprevot/CudaD3D12Update/blob/e2284f4876059af492be9a8e68a5c587fd2ca7fb/simpleD3D12update.cpp#L321). The texture is defined as such:

```
    TextureChannels = 4;
    TextureWidth = m_width;
    TextureHeight = m_height;
    const auto textureSurface = TextureWidth * TextureHeight;
    const auto texturePixels = textureSurface * TextureChannels;
    const auto textureSizeBytes = sizeof(float)* texturePixels;

    const auto texFormat = TextureChannels == 4 ? DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT : DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT;
    const auto texDesc = CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Tex2D(texFormat, TextureWidth, TextureHeight, 1, 1, 1, 0, D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_ALLOW_SIMULTANEOUS_ACCESS);
    ThrowIfFailed(m_device->CreateCommittedResource(&CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT), D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_SHARED,
        &texDesc, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PIXEL_SHADER_RESOURCE, nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS(&TextureArray)));
    NAME_D3D12_OBJECT(TextureArray);
```

Then the DX12 texture is [imported into cuda as a surface](https://github.com/mprevot/CudaD3D12Update/blob/e2284f4876059af492be9a8e68a5c587fd2ca7fb/simpleD3D12update.cpp#L357), then you [run a kernel](https://github.com/mprevot/CudaD3D12Update/blob/master/TextureKernel.cu) (or shader in the language of DX) to modify it. The good thing is that you do not have to update it at a predefined frequency, the surface can be updated and displayed at will, an only then.

If you do not have a cuda GPU, you can just change the texture from the CPU (cf DX samples).

However, even though you did not ask for this, I believe it will be a loat easier to use something like a WPF framework to display (and compute) such image, the latencies will be a lot bigger but very acceptable, and you can only display 8bit images. In the back WPF is relying on DX, but to my knowledge one can't modify its configuration. That's the way to go to get a result and to play with that ASAP .

Answer (score -2):

> All what i need is to display a surface in a win32 window. Say 256 * 256 xRGB and i need to get access to the memory to put pixels in it.

If that's all you need, I suggest you stick with GDI/GDI+. It's less performant since it's fully software implemented, but it's very easy to use.

> I know there are different ways to do the same in Dirct3D 10 and 11, But does it involve playing with 3d things?

Only insofar as setting up the 2D projections (which are set up by default).

> I used surface->Lock() in direct3D9, but it isn't available in newer ones.

The modern way of uploading resource data is using [`ID3D12Resource::Map`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-id3d12resource-map).

> So, said that if i have to use a lib (like SDL) which i cannot call directly to lock the surface and show in a win32 window

What do you mean, SDL is a layer on top of the basic 3D APIs, OGL/D3D. It supports everything they support. Specifically, locking SDL textures is done with [`SDL_LockTexture`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_LockTexture).

Comment: They could use [Direct2D](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-portal) as well, which is intended for this purpose.

Comment: D2D is a (dead) layer on top of D3D9, and a thin one at that. It's not difficult to reimplement the needed portions in D3D12.

Comment: Drect2D is not a dead layer on top of D3D9. It can be used with D3D11, and D3D12 using D3D11on12 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/d2d-using-d3d11on12

Comment: @Blindy D2D is very very much not dead, it is very well supported and used as the underlying technology for the XAML UI